# \printglossary destroys table counter and hyperref

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, glossaries, counters

first of all, I would like to point out that this is my second larger work in LaTex. Through the first I could already gather some experience, but unfortunately I can't get any further here.

The major issue is, that in the `\listoftables` the numbering starts at 1 while in the caption of the table itself it starts with *Tabelle 2* (so the numbering is for some reason increased by 1). Furthermore the hyperref from the `\listoftables` to the table is also not working, it will always jump to the title page (I'll would guess a default fallback behavior if the reference cannot be found).

**What I'll found out:**
After some countless and unsuccessful internet research I'll tried to narrow down the spot where the issue first appears. As it appears to me all is related to the `\printglossary` (with or without parameter). If the Glossary is either not defined or printed the numbering and hyperref for the `\listoftables` and tables itself is working.

I'll would be happy if someone has an idea or can point out what I'm doing wrong / using wrongly. Thanks in advance!

MWE (I hope it works):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[ngermanb]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[style=long,nonumberlist,toc,acronym,xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
   backend=biber,
   style=authoryear
]{biblatex}

\newacronym{BSD}{BSD}{Berkeley Software Distribution}

\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.25}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=gray},font={color=gray}}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=10pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=gray},font={color=gray}}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks,
   citecolor=black,
   filecolor=black,
   linkcolor=black,
   urlcolor=black
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{\thepage}
\lhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\chead{ }
\cfoot{ }

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
   \maketitle  
   
   \pagenumbering{Roman}
   
   \newpage
   \enlargethispage{-20mm}
   \tableofcontents
   \clearpage
   
   \begin{onehalfspace}    
       
   \listoffigures
   \clearpage
   
   \listoftables
   \clearpage
   
   
   \printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
   % \setcounter{table}{0} <-- With this one I can fix the impact but not the cause :(
   \clearpage
       
   \pagenumbering{arabic}
   
   \parindent=0pt
   \parskip=6pt
   \linespread{1.25}

   \section{Section 1}
   This is some text with an acronym \gls{BSD}.
   \begin{table}[!ht]
       \begin{center}
           \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5em}
           \def\arraystretch{1.25}
           \caption{This is some Table}
           \label{SomeTable}
           \begin{tabular}{lcc}
               Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
               \hline          
               Content 1 & Content 2 & Content 3 \\
               \hline
           \end{tabular}
       \end{center}    
   \end{table}
   \newpage
   
   \clearpage
   
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
   \printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
   
   \end{onehalfspace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test now, but imho glossaries uses internally longtable and longtable increases the table counter.

Comment: Try with `\AddToHookNext{env/longtable/begin}{\let\refstepcounter\relax}` before the `\printglossary` (but I'm not sure if the glossary internally needs \refstepcounter too ...). And your constant use of \clearpage and pagenumbering indicates that you should better use a book class (scrbook) and \frontmatter/\mainmatter.

Comment: I think cleaner is `\AddToHook{env/theglossary/end}{\addtocounter{table}{-1}}`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. The `\AddToHook{env/theglossary/end}{\addtocounter{table}{-1}}` as well as the `\AddToHookNext{env/longtable/begin}{\let\refstepcounter\relax}` are bot working but result in the same behavior as `\setcounter{table}{0}` after the `\printglossary`. The numbering in the `\listoftables` an the tables itself is then correct but the hyperref is still leading to the title page.

With this further information I'll will try in parallel to find something with the big search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ulrike is right, `longtable` increases the `table` counter, even when there is no `\caption`, in contrast to the normal `table` environment. I think this could be considered a bug in `glossaries`. Here is my solution which goes a bit further than my comment. The solution in my comment would no longer work if this was corrected in `glossaries`. The solution below works in either case. It just saves the `table` counter at the start of the glossary and restores it at the end.

```
\newcounter{mysavetablecounter}
\AddToHook{env/theglossary/begin}{\setcounter{mysavetablecounter}{\value{table}}}
\AddToHook{env/theglossary/end}{\setcounter{table}{\value{mysavetablecounter}}}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This answere not only solved the issue it also pointed me a little more in the right direction how to question issues in LaTex in order to correctly search for them!